# Distinct records based on multiple fields using Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Input data set:

```
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5
101,a1,a11,a111,a1111
102,a1,a11,a111,a1111
103,a1,a11,a111,a1111
201,b1,b11,b111,b1111
202,b1,b11,b111,b1111
```

Below query will give distinct records in Pig.

```
details = load 'emp.csv' using PigStorage(',')  AS (field1:chararray,field2:chararray,field3:chararray,field4:chararray,field5:chararray);
distinct_detials = DISTINCT details;
```

I have a use case where I need to get distinct records based on field2,field3,field4.

Expected output is

```
101,a1,a11,a111,a1111
202,b1,b11,b111,b1111
```

Comment: I don't understand the _Expected Output_. `field1` is unique in all 5 lines,  so even if you use `group details by (field2, field3, field5)` , you're gonna get all 5 rows when you do a distinct because of `field1`.

Comment: I want to find distinct records based on field2,field3,field4. The field1,field5 values can be one of the record values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested foreach to accomplish what you want:

```
details = load 'emp.csv' using PigStorage(',')  AS (field1:chararray,field2:chararray,field3:chararray,field4:chararray,field5:chararray);
distinct_detials = foreach (GROUP details by (field2, field3, field4) ) {
    temp_rel = details.(field1, field5);
    temp_limit = LIMIT temp_rel 1;
    generate FLATTEN(temp_limit) as (field1, field5), FLATTEN(group) as (field2, field3, field4);
}
DUMP distinct_details;
```

This will give the following output:

```
(103,a1111,a1,a11,a111)
(202,b1111,b1,b11,b111)
```

You can further use a `foreach` on `distinct_details` to bring the fields in order.